# Should the "linked questions" menu show questions where the link is tied to deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I was poking around a few older questions, and I came to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317224/how-do-i-dance). [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317769/what-does-the-flashing-ghost-icon-mean) appeared in the linked questions menu, so I clicked on to see what it was.

After viewing the question, I saw a comment with a link to the original question on an answer that has since been deleted due to being spam-like. Since I have over 10,000 rep and can see deleted answers, I didn't think anything of it at first. However, I opened a different browser to see how this looked while not logged in. To my surprise, the linked question still appeared.

So my question is: Should linked questions still show up if the link tied to a deleted answer? 
As a new user, or a user without high enough reputation, this would seem confusing as they would not be able to see the delete answer and have no indication to why they are linked.